# Android switching activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 activities. One called `Login` and another called `ListDeals`. `Login` has a form with a submit button which, when pressed, should switch our activity to `ListDeals`. This works.

However, in Logcat I don't get a message saying that the activity has started. Also, when in `ListDeals`, if the user presses the back button, both activities should be killed. I looked around and this is what I came up with:

```
public class Login extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

    Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(onSubmit);
}

private View.OnClickListener onSubmit=new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(view.getContext(),ListDeals.class );
        startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);

    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==2) {
        finish();
    } 
}

}
```

---

```
public class ListDeals extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.deals_list);
        System.out.println("starting activity");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        System.out.println("dude");
        setResult(2);
        super.onDestroy();


    }

    protected void onStop(){
        setResult(2);
        super.onStop();

    }

}
```

However, when I press the back button, It takes me back to the `Login` activity which is not what I want.

Comment: The answers given address your problem just fine.  But I felt it necessary to point out that the reason your code doesn't work is because calling `setResult()` inside of `onDestroy()` or `onStop()` is setting that value too late.  The result has already been delivered to the parent `Activity` at that point.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I said that he doesn't need the result. He can just erase all that out completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your click handler, `onSubmit`, just finish your login activity, like this. That way, it won't be on the activity stack, and as a result, pressing back from your other activity will bring the user back to where they started.

```
private View.OnClickListener onSubmit=new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(view.getContext(),ListDeals.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }
};
```

Also, to address you second question, use the [Log class methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html), such as `Log.i` or `Log.d` for debug messages, those will show up in logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Finish Login before starting the new Activity. Besides you don't need the result.

```
private View.OnClickListener onSubmit=new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(Login.this, ListDeals.class );
        startActivity(myIntent);
        Login.this.finish() // add this to finish it.

    }
};
```

Comment: That seemed to work but the issues is that the line System.out.println("starting activity"); is not executed. Its almost as if the views have switched but the code in the activity ListDeals is not executed. Any idea why?

Comment: In Android, you don't debug with `System.out`, you do it with the `Log` class. Please take a quick look here: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html Don't worry, it's very simple... it has a few methods and that's all. :-)

Comment: if you need any other help, feel free to ask.